# No puedo entrar a mi Wordpress (Pagina Empresa Ayuda)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-plugin

Esta es la web de mi empresa

https://www.ciolab.es/

La utilizo todos los días, es en la que los clientes me hacen pedidos.

Sin ella estoy perdido, a raíz de intentar arreglar algunos problemas que han surgido hoy.

Así ha terminado, sin poder entrar ni si quiera yo.

Ni si quiera tengo el archivo .htaccess ni se como empezar

Llevo más de 5 horas intentando arreglarlo, el problema que necesito acceder O SI O SI, o perderé miles de datos.

Porfavor, necesito ayuda, gracias

Comment: Hola @Javier Avila Fernandez, para poder ayudarte necesitamos saber exactamente que es lo que hiciste, un mensaje de error, código que modificaste o algo que nos ayude a identificar que esta funcionando mal. Con solo la descripción del problema que nos proporcionaste es complicado ayudarte.

Comment: Hola! Mira, al parece el plugin user acces manager me daba error, lo eliminé y se solucionó, aun que después, sin querer, me cargué el plugin del ssl, cosa que fue el desastre numero uno, al intentar tocar el htacess, lo eliminé también. En lo que he ido intentando arreglar, hasta aquí mas o menos es lo que ha pasado, en resumen, no puedo entrar de ninguna de las maneras

Comment: Hola Javier, ¿tienes acceso a la raiz del wordpress es decir al hosting?¿Tienes copia de seguridad?

Comment: Si, los archivos los tengo todos, y la base de datos también, aun así no es suficiente según tengo entendido

Comment: Menudo berenjenal

Comment: tenes acceso ssh? o ftp? por el momento parece que hay una re dirección infinita y hay trazas de cloudflare. Desactivar SSL y borrar cache en cloudflare te podría permitir acceder al sitio pero todo depende de cómo esten el htacces y las cosas que hagan plugins de redirección

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que presenta tu sitio se debe a un bucle de redireccionamiento. Antes de que le muevas a cualquier cosa en archivos de tu sitio o base de datos, prueba lo siguiente:

Si has perdido el .htaccess generalo nuevamente:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Si usas SSL tu .htaccess debe quedar mas o menos así:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Borra tus cookies (las de tu sitio) y prueba...

Observa si tienes el mismo problema. Si es así, y para averiguar que lo está causando y tratar de resolver el problema, prueba a entrar al tu FTP y deshabilitar los plugins (cambia el nombre de la carpeta por cualquier otro, más tarde lo restauras). Si el error desaparece al deshabilitar los plugins ahora restaura el nombre de la carpeta y prueba a realizar el mismo procedimiento con cada uno de los plugins para determinar cual o cuales están provocando el problema.

Recuerda borrar las cookies y archivos temporales en cada intento. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias! Este htacess me ha servido, para recuperar el acceso, por otra parte he conseguido restaurar la base de datos, a unas horas atrás, y he conseguido tener todo funcionando. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Excelente amigo, ahora presta atención a quienes tengan acceso a tu sitio y a tus propios mantenimientos, que ocurra esto no el algo normal que pase por si solo. saludos!

Comment: Por cierto, si la respuesta te dio la solución o parte de ella, estaría genial que la marques como aceptada... saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu problema es que borraste o editates el .htaccess y tienes acceso al servidor, crea un nuevo archivo en la raiz de la pagina con lo siguiente:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Suerte!